# How to select HEX values / colors in Inkscape

Tags: website-design, color, inkscape

How to select web colors in Inkscape? I know that I can select the ">" at the bottom-right of the screen and select WebHex and then select one in the bar. But in that bar there are just a few colors. How to select a color that is not in the bar? is there a way to put the color in numbers?

For instance, if I have a square, I select it and I want to give it the color #666666

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to use the `Fill and Stroke` window. This gives you more control over assign color to a stroke (the "outline" of an object), the fill (the inside of it), and what the stroke looks like (thickness, dashed vs solid, etc)

1. Select the object that you want to assign a color to.
2. Click `Object > Fill and Stroke` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
3. On the `Fill` tab, change the color as needed.

Since you want to assign a specific hex color, enter it into the `RGBA` box (don't include the `#`). Note that this is RGBA, not RGB--the extra two characters on the end represent opacity (ff being solid; 00 being fully transparent). So to assign #666666, you would want to enter #666666ff

Comment: This is estrange, I have to put a hex color in the RGBA box? So, why is this box called RGBA by Inkscape?

Comment: It is technically correct. What people usually call a "hex color" is an RGB value converted to hex--it's still an RGB color. For example, your #666666 is really rgb(102,102,102) converted from decimal to hexadecimal. Hex colors are still in RGB. In Inkscape, the team probably decided that "RGBA" easier to understand since it includes the alpha channel as well.

Comment: It is simple a bad design from Inkscape. That's the difference with a proper software like Illustrator. Here things are unexpected and complicated

Comment: So let me understand Alvaro, if someone puts something different in their development than in the software you use, it means its improper software? Maybe instead of saying its bad design, you could think it makes the alpha more accessible. Maybe its just you are not used to think if everything is not friendly

Comment: zardilior - that's not how ux works.  If people in software expect rgb and hex to be different since that's how most other tools expose them, then devs expect that moving onto different tools.  It is indeed a bad design choice from inkscape, but an understandable one given it is free software.  Free software often doesn't prioritize ux

Answer (score -1):

Zardilior, no, it's about giving us options.  Almost all programs allow you to use either HEX or RGB/RGBA.  Inkscape leaving out a proper HEX option is silly.

Comment: As you can see in [my answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/58675/16458), this is not true. You can enter RGB colors in hexidecimal form in Inkscape.